# Проблема компиляции yacc lex error: ‘yylval’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: bison, lex, yacc

Я столкнулся с проблемой при компиляции lex/yacc файлов.

Файл file.l:

```
%{
#define YYSTYPE double
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
-?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+ {yylval = atof(yytext); return NUMBER;}
-?[0-9]+ {yylval = atof(yytext); return  NUMBER;}
[\t\n]          {return '\n';}
.|\n  ;
```

Файл file.y:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define YYSTYPE double
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char const *);
%}

%token NUMBER
%%
input: 
    | input line;

line: '\n' {printf("Empty line\n");}
    | error '\n'  {yyerrok;}
    | expr;

expr: NUMBER '\n' { printf("%d\n", (int) ceil($1)); }
;
%%
int main() {
      return yyparse();
}

void yyerror(char const *s)
{
     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);      
}
```

Компилирую таким образом:

```
lex file.l
yacc -d file.y
cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c
```

Получаю такую ошибку

```
file.l: In function ‘yylex’:
file.l:6:2: error: ‘yylval’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 -?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+ {yylval = atof(yytext); return NUMBER;}
  ^
file.l:6:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Кажется, я сделал все, чтобы предотвратить данную ошибку. Тем не менее она появляется снова и снова.